# How to find a hyperplane

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, separation-axioms

Let $A, B ⊂ \mathbb{R}^n$ be two nonempty sets such that $A ∩ B = ∅$. 
$H(A, B) := \{(w, d) ∈ \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : \sup_{x\in A} \langle w,x\rangle ≤ d ≤ \inf_{y \in B} \langle w, y\rangle \}$

How do I find $H(A,B)$ explicitly for when

$A:=\{x_1,x_2\} \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_1 \leq 0\}$

$B:= \{x_1,x_2\} \in \mathbb{R}^2: x_1 > 0 \}$

Comment: The second set is empty. I suspect a typo.

Comment: @MichaelGrant sorry, it was meant to be a 0, fixed

Comment: Then $w=(1,0)$ and $d=0$ by inspection.

Comment: What would be the method you would apply to cpmpute the hyperplane in a more complicated/general case? This isn't mentioned in my lecture notes

Comment: I don't have one, sorry.

Comment: was there any means by which you came accross your answer? I am reading up on the topic again, but don't see what you must have done.

Comment: No, it just seems obvious to me. The two sets share a boundary $x_1=0$, and that's a hyperplane, so... done.